# how to get args from node object of rosjava Node class?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
While running rosjava node we receive "node" object in onStart(Node node) function. Can we extract command line args from this "node" object. I tried to get NodeConfiguration and ParameterTree but did not work. Any idea?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42646/how-to-get-args-from-node-object-of-rosjava-node-class?/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Command line arguments are not yet supported. I suggest using the parameter server. Also, feel free to file a feature request.

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0